# Content Negotiation using Spring Repository

Tags: json, xml, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using Spring Boot Application to provide my RESTful API. I am trying to provide both xml and json responses using the same URI. It is easily doable using Rest Controllers in Spring for example:

> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = "/example", produces = { "application/xml", "application/json" })
> @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
> public Person index() {
>   Person person = new Person();
>   person.setName("Adam");
>   return person;
> }
> ```

If jackson library is in the classpath, Spring will either return serialized Person object based an the 'accept' header being passed.

Is there a way to get it done using Spring Repositories? Ideally I would be looking for something like this:

> @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "person", path =
>   "person", produces = { "application/xml", "application/json" }) public
>   interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository {
>
> }

If there is no simple way of doing it, what's the best approach to get it done?

Comment: Found a solution?